# how to change time zone in kiwiTCMS?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

i change the time zone first, and then restart the service, but the time is still the UTC time

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

how can i change it?
￼￼

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need to see an example of your code and it also helps to share what you tried and what were the outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The application doesn't support time zones and the docker image is configured for UTC. If you configure the host time to be UTC then the timestamps displayed in the web interface should be correct.